# How to Create a PostgreSQL database with different Encoding?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, encoding

I want to create a New Database that will store data in German(i.e Text with accents etc). Hence I tried to create it using the following SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
  WITH ENCODING='LATIN1'
       OWNER=postgres
       TEMPLATE=template0
       CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```

When I run this on my Windows Development machine, I get the following error message:

> ERROR:  encoding "LATIN1" does not match locale "English_United
>   States.1252" 
>   DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "WIN1252".

On my Linux server, I get the following error message:

> ERROR:  encoding "LATIN1" does not match locale "en_US.UTF-8"
>   DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "UTF8".

What do I need to do to create a Database which can correctly store German text?

Comment: Can you specify which Linux distribution you use ?

Comment: @SahapAsci: Ubuntu 16:04 LTS, 64 Bit

Comment: can you try `de_DE.UTF-8`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux,
I was able to create a database with encoding `LATIN1` by 1st initializing the database using `initdb` in `\usr\pgsql-10\bin` as `initdb --encoding=en_US.iso88591`. Read more about [localization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/charset.html) and available [character set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html) support.

Then restart the service using-

`systemctl restart postgresql-10`

This will re-initialize the template databases template0 and template1 with the new encoding and then you can create the database using

`createdb <dbname>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the site below for choose your character, then use example:

http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg82/multibyte.html#CHARSET-TABLE

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE database_name 
          WITH TABLESPACE tablespace_name TEMPLATE = template0 
          OWNER = database_user ENCODING 'WIN1252' 
         LC_CTYPE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252' LC_COLLATE = 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252';

CREATE DATABASE
```